# ng-if="true" + data-ng-if="true" evaluates to false?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The fact is that if you use `ng-if="truthyValue"` and `data-ng-if="truthyValue"` inside an **html** element using **angularJS** +1.6, the affected element won't render in the **DOM**. This is true even if you use `ng-if` and `data-ng-if` with the **boolean** `true`.

---

Does anybody knows why does this happen ?

Comment: Interesting. Repro for those who want to try: http://plnkr.co/edit/puftVkA1SoGHfIayaNIn?p=preview But anyway, why would you want to do this? `ng-if` and `data-ng-if` are two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: I don't want to do it, not by purpose of course; but I did it by mistake and I really want to know why does this happen so I could learn even more about the framework.

Comment: Interestingly, you can also use `ng-attr-data-ng-if="true"` and indeed chain `ng-attr`s, so `ng-attr-ng-attr-ng-attr-ng-attr-ng-if="true"` also works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer takes multiple quotes of AngularJS's [directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

---

The reason for this is that AngularJS HTML templates are *compiled*:

> For AngularJS, "compilation" means attaching directives to the HTML to make it interactive.

During compilation, template directives undergo a process called *Normalization* which involves changing HTMLs case-insensitive names to the camelCase names used in AngularJS, this follows the following process:

> 1. Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
> 2. Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to camelCase.

After this process you can see that you'll have **two** `ngIf` directives attached to the same HTML element, these then interfere (the reason it works for two occurrences of `ng-if` but not an `ng-if` and an `data-ng-if` is that your web browser discards one of the `ng-if`s if there are two rather than them both reaching the AngularJS compiler).

---

Thus the solution for this not to occur is *don't use multiple directives in your HTML which AngularJS normalizes to the same thing*.

Answer (score -2):

So after experimenting with this, it looks like it's working just fine, using Angular 1.6.5

You are not supposed to use both data-ng-if and ng-if on the same element anyway. Stick with one of them.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-if="false">hello there</div>
    <div ng-if="true">whats up</div>
  </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {


}]);
```

Here is a codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxoXgE

This behavior is not only seen in ng-if but also other angular directives such as ng-repeat. Of course, removing one of the declaration fixes the error immediately.

Here is an example that doesn't work, using both `ng-repeat` and `data-ng-repeat`:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvjdZV

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It is not a bug I couldn't fix, it is just a curious behavior I want to understand.

Comment: I know. I'm just showing you how it is meant to be used so that it does work. I agree with you that it's weird that just true doesn't work. Apparently someone thought my answer was not good enough and downvoted!

Comment: I think you got downvoted because you did not concern the main question facts.