# How to use dynamic scope variable inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What i want is to be ng-if="male"/ng-if="female"//ng-if="all" but getting as it is data-ng-if="AnswerList2[index][GenderTypeAnswer]" true and false which is working fine with data-ng-show, but i don't want to show the element in DOM.

```js
var sampleData=[{
        "QuestionId": 1,
        "Question": "Please tick the box that applies to you",
        "AnswerList": [
            {
                "AnswerId": 1,
                "Answer": "Male",
                "GenderTypeAnswer": "male"
            },
            {
                "AnswerId": 2,
                "Answer": "Female",
                "GenderTypeAnswer": "female"
            },
            {
                "AnswerId": 3,
                "Answer": "NA",
                "GenderTypeAnswer": "all"
            }
        ]
    }];
     $scope.all=true;
     $scope.male=true; 
     $scope.female=false;
```

```html
<p data-ng-repeat="(index,value) in sampleData[0]['AnswerList'] as AnswerList2" data-ng-if="AnswerList2[index][GenderTypeAnswer]" data-ng-bind-html="AnswerList2[index]['Answer']"></p>
```

I am using some json which has some value in key 'GenderTypeAnswer' which indeed i am using it as scope variable in js with same name as the value, but not able to get the value in ng-if, any help ?

This is it

AnswerListLast[index]['GenderTypeAnswer'] is coming as it is in ng-if.

Comment: <div data-ng-repeat="(index,value) in QuestionJson[9]['AnswerList'] as AnswerListLast"  data-ng-if="AnswerListLast[index]['GenderTypeAnswer']">  <p>This is it</p  ></div>

Comment: Provide code where you are using it

Comment: <div data-ng-repeat="(index,value) in QuestionJson[9]['AnswerList'] as AnswerListLast" data-ng-if="AnswerListLast[index]['GenderTypeAnswer']"> <p>This is it</p ></div>   @AbirAdak this is the code

Answer (score 0):

If you sure AnswerListLast[index]['GenderTypeAnswer'] contains a value then try ng-if instead of data-ng-if...
Follow This
[ng-if="true" + data-ng-if="true" evaluates to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098315/ng-if-true-data-ng-if-true-evaluates-to-false)

Comment: AnswerListLast[index]['GenderTypeAnswer'] contains 'gender' which am using in js as $scope.gender =true; or $scope.gender =false; conditionally over a code.

Comment: ng-if taking it as false every time because it is'gender' which is not true. I want it to be render as variable and get its value through js.

Comment: Can you make a stackbitz example